# Angular : accepting cookie send by backend

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, spring-boot

So, I'm currently working on session management and found out that one of the ways of doing so is by using cookies. I'm using spring boot as my backend tool.
So,

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public User addUser(@RequestBody String name, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    
    HttpSession getSession = (HttpSession) request.getAttribute("session");
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("sessionId", getSession.getId());
    response.addCookie(cookie);

    sessionService.addSession(getSession);

    String session = (String) getSession.getId();
    System.out.println("Session id is " + session);
    User newUser = new User(name, session);
    userService.addUser(newUser);

    return newUser;
}
```

This is the code that's responsible for creating cookies. Where, what happen is user will enter the username on a form and click on submit and then it will be post mapped on this method.

So, I tried checking if I'm getting cookies from frontend or not using this method

```
@PostMapping("/noOfUsers")
public int userCount(@RequestBody String sessionId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(request.getSession().getId());
     Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
     if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
              if (cookie.getName().equals("sessionId")) {
                 System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
              }
            }
          }


    return this.userService.noOfUser();
}
```

When I used postman, I did get the cookie value printed but don't know how in angular I'm suppose to accept the cookie send by backend and in the end send back the cookie on each request made using frontend.

Comment: "accept the cookie send by backend and in the end send back the cookie on each request made using frontend" - I don't believe you have to do anything, that should happen behind framework's back. Did you look in the browser's dev tools if cookies are sent, saved  and sent back?

Comment: @mbojko well I was using ngx-cookie-service where I set the cookie by myself and yeah I did saw that cookie in dev tool but the one send by backend, I saw it anywhere.